# Добавляется приставка System. в C#

Tags: c#

Установил *Visual Studio*, пишу `ConsoleWriteline` автозаполнением(CW), а система ругается и автоматом добавляет `System.ConsoleWriteline`, если `System.` убрать, то не компилируется и выдает ошибку CS0234.

---

**UPD**

Мой код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console.Net
{
    class Car
    {
        protected virtual void StartEngine()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Двигатель запущен!");
        }
        public virtual void Drive()
        {
            StartEngine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Я машина, я еду");
        }
    }

    class ElectroCar : Car
    {
        protected override void StartEngine()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Питание включено!");
        }
        public override void Drive()
        {
            StartEngine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Я электромобиль, я еду");
        }
    }
    class Person
    {
        public void Drive(Car car)
        {
            car.Drive(); 
        }
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.Drive(new ElectroCar());
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код проекта покажите полностью.

Comment: `namespace Console.Net` Так у вас консоль в пространстве имён, вот компилятору и нужна подсказка, чтобы понять, какую из консолей использовать.

Comment: Ого. Вот так нюанс. Спасибо за помощь всем!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего до неймспейса не хватает подключение неймспейса System вот так

```
using System;
```

и тогда можно писать

```
Console.WriteLine
```

обратите внимание на точку, после слова `Console`

Общий код примерно должен быть таким

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld {
    class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

`namespace` можно опустить и просто писать сразу класс и метод. Но обычно используется

---

**UPD**

Судя по представленному коду:

Идёт конфликт с вашем собственным пространством имен (`namespace Console.Net`), у вас `WriteLine` пытается найти в вашем собственном `Console.`. Компилятору и нужна подсказка, чтобы понять, какую из консолей использовать.

Не используйте системные названия и будет все хорошо.

Comment: Там автоматом при создании файла .net framework подключено все неймспейсы. Я пишу CW, нажимаю TAB и система автоматом создает конструкцию System.Console.WriteLine . Если System. убрать, то выдает ошибку  CS0234.

Comment: Знаете, я вам не верю

Comment: Полный код в студию

Comment: Ошибка CS0234 Тип или имя пространства имен "WriteLine" не существует в пространстве имен "Console" (возможно, отсутствует ссылка на сборку).

Comment: @LikeTonyFerguson Такое может быть если в проекте есть еще один класс, который назван как `Console`. В этом случае происходит конфликт, из-за которого надо явно прописывать из какого `namespace` брать класс.

Comment: Добавил код выше

Comment: @LikeTonyFerguson Как и сказал выше, у вас конфликт с вашем собственным пространством имен (`namespace Console.Net`), у вас `WriteLine` пытается найти в вашем собственном `Console`. Не используйте системные названия и будет все хорошо. P.S. Код надо вставлять в первый вопрос (кнопка "Править" под ним, а не в виде **ответа**, будте внимательней!

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: 2 голоса, но этот ответ не отвечает правильно оформленный на вопрос.

Comment: @aepot ...почему?

Comment: А
, не увидел что дополнено. В таком случае @LikeTonyFerguson чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console.Net
{
    class Car
    {
        protected virtual void StartEngine()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Двигатель запущен!");
        }
        public virtual void Drive()
        {
            StartEngine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Я машина, я еду");
        }
    }

    class ElectroCar : Car
    {
        protected override void StartEngine()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Питание включено!");
        }
        public override void Drive()
        {
            StartEngine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Я электромобиль, я еду");
        }
    }
    class Person
    {
        public void Drive(Car car)
        {
            car.Drive(); 
        }
    }
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.Drive(new ElectroCar());
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите